Feyncalc computations using parallel computing (multicore computing)?
I'm doing very long computations with FeynCalc (they're dimensional regularizations of diagrams with a lot of D-dimensional metric and D-dimensional momentum contractions like Contract[ MTD[$\alpha,\beta$] MTD[$\beta,\gamma$] FVD[p,$\delta$]... ] involved). For the first diagram I computed, it took almost 6 days working full time to give the result (my laptop is corei5 10th gen, 4 cores, 32GB RAM).
Looking into Mathematica documentation, I found that it's possible to do computations faster using parallel computing, i.e. using more than one kernel/core to do one single computation. This can be done with the Parallelize function. Unfortunately, when I try to parallelize the contraction expression (for example, Parallelize[Contract[MTD[$\alpha, \beta$]MTD[$\alpha,\beta$]]]), I get the message "(expr) cannot be parallelized; proceeding with sequential evaluation".
Is there some way to use parallel computing in FeynCalc (to take advantage of all the CPU's cores available) or if any other way exists to make computations faster. In fact, I have access to a 16-core PC at my university, but I think this PC would not be helpful as long as parallel computing is not possible, right? Any suggestions?
Any information or advice is helpful.

When running one of these commands how many cores and how much RAM is used? If things are under control (eg 1 core, a few GBs of RAM), it might be possible to run several commands simultaneously via ParallelTable[] or similar. Some commands like Integrate are not parallelizable or others like Dot are already parallelized and heavily optimized (these two are probably under the hood in the regularization and the contraction).

I forgot to mention that personally, I wouldn't leave my laptop running for 6 days straight at 100% CPU usage... Maybe try running on a workstation or a cluster, if one is available

@HansOlo It uses one single core and around 40% of RAM when I run it, so yes, it's under control. It may be possible to run several commands simultaneously on different kernels, but what I need is to use more than one kernel/core to run one single command. A workstation or cluster is a great idea, but first, I must know how to parallelize this FeynCalc code.
